# Add tab index via CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add a -1 `tabindex` to input fields using CSS? Or any other way to exlude certain input fields from the tabindexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Tab index" isn't a *style* of an element, so I doubt it.

Comment: Was afraid for that answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: tab-index is a element attribute